# How do I create a transparent UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, uitextview

On my 1) `UIView` one (2) `UIImageView` will be on this (3) `UITextView`.

This `UITextView` must be Transparent and we have to view the `imageView`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Objective-C

If you only want to make the background (rather than the whole UITextView) transparent, I believe you should be do this via the backgroundColor property it inherits from UIView.

As such...

```
[yourTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

...should hopefully do the trick.

If however, you want to make the *whole* UITextView transparent, the alpha property @taskinoor mentions is perfect.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the alpha of text view to any desired value.

```
myTextView.alpha = 0.5;    // 50% transparent
```

Comment: Won't the alpha property affect everything (text included)? Then again, perhaps that's what he wants. (Hard to tell from the question.)

Comment: Ya, text also be changed. It guess that's what he is looking for. Otherwise I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: hi Taskinoor i am looking for UITextView must be Transparent without effecting the Text on it,

Comment: @Nandakishore, try the answer of middaparka then. You can create UIColor with specific alpha value by using UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha method.

Answer (score 9):

1. Go down to the utilities panel (on the right) and scroll down to the "View" section.
2. Then, see the "Background" field. I already have my UITextField/UITextView transparent.  Your's should have a solid color, right?  That means that the object is not transparent.
   [image]
3. Open the pop-up menu and press "Clear Color".  Then, you must see the color to be half black and half white (like mine). That is how Xcode signifies transparency.

Then, you are done (you don't have to deal with **any** code if I understand you correctly)!

Answer (score 7):

I use in this way:

```
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; //clear background
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone]; //clear borders
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 and higher**

For Swift 4 use this:

```
yourTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```